# Unable to close modal: setter function used to change variable state which closes modal never executes

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, modal-dialog

Right now I'm working on a menu page for a website on the client side using Next.js. When the menu for a restaurant renders, each list item represents an item on the menu. Each menu item has its own modal and an `onClick` prop that takes a handler which calls a `setOpenModalId` setter function to set `openModalId` variable state. This tells the browser which modal to display when the page rerenders.

I'm able to bring up a modal for each item using a `handleItemClick` handler that calls the `setOpenModalId` setter, but when I call the `closeModal` handler which should set the `openModalId` state to `null`, effectively closing the modal on rerender, the `setOpenModalId` setter never appears to execute at all. In the example below, the `onClose` handler should be invoked when clicking the `div` that represents the modal backdrop or when clicking the `figure` that wraps an "X" icon in the modal itself. When the "X" icon is clicked, the `onClose` handler is invoked and `"Nothing happening"` is logged to the browser console, but the setter never appears to execute.

I'm aware that `useState` setter calls are asynchronous and the state change isn't reflected immediately, and I have a `useEffect` hook with the `openModalId` state variable as a dependency set up to log the value of `openModalId` when it finally does change. The issue isn't that the state isn't changing immediately, it's that it doesn't appear to update at all, and I'm never able to close a modal once it's opened.

I've set up a context to share the state and a `useModal` custom hook for functionality that manages the state. The context provider is used in the `layout.jsx` page that wraps the child components where the custom hook and state are used.

I've spent longer than I'd like on this issue, and I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Sorry I can't be more specific. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here's the relevant code:

```js
// ModalContext.jsx
"use client";
import React, {createContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
const ModalContext = createContext(null);

const ModalProvider = props => {
  const [openModalId, setOpenModalId] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(openModalId + " (at ModalContext)");
  }, [openModalId]);

  return (
    <ModalContext.Provider 
      value={{openModalId, setOpenModalId}}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ModalContext.Provider>
  );
};

export {ModalContext, ModalProvider};
```

```js
// useModal.jsx
"use client";
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import { ModalContext } from '../contexts/ModalContext';
import getCopy from '../app/lib/utils/getCopy';

const useModal = () => {
  const {openModalId, setOpenModalId} = useContext(ModalContext);

  const handleItemClick = (item) => {
    setOpenModalId(item.id)
  };

  const closeModal = () => {
    console.log("Nothing Happening"); // Nothing Happening
    setOpenModalId(null);
  };

  return {
    closeModal, 
    handleItemClick,
    openModalId,
    setOpenModalId
  };
};

export default useModal;
```

```js
// page.jsx
function FoodCategory({category, items}) {
  const {closeModal, openModalId, handleItemClick} = useModal();
  return (
    <li>
    <h3>{category}</h3>
    <section>
      <ul>
        {items.map((item) => {
          return (
            <li
              key={item.id}
              onClick={() => {handleItemClick(item)}}
            >
              {
                openModalId === item.id && (
                  <CartModal 
                    item={item} 
                    isOpen={true} 
                    onClose={closeModal} 
                    pathname={"Menu"} 
                  />
                )
              }

            
           // code omitted...


            </li>
          )
        })}
      </ul>
    </section>
  </li>
  )
}
```

```js
// CartModal.jsx
import { GrClose } from "react-icons/gr";

function CartModal({item, isOpen, onClose, pathname}) {
  if (!isOpen) return null;

  // code omitted...

  return (
    <div onClick={onClose} className='modal'>
      <div className='modal-content'>
        <div>
          <figure 
            onClick={onClose} 
           >
            <GrClose />
          </figure>
        </div>

     // Code omitted...
   
     </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```